# Modernizr no esta definido

Tags: modernizr

[image: modernizr no esta definido]

A alguien le ha llegado a ocurrir este tipo de error? saben como puedo corregirlo?

Comment: puedes mostrar por favor la línea donde estas invocando la librería?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Asumo que esta saliendo ese error por que te hace falta declarar correctamente tanto la librería de `Modernizr` y la de `JQuery`; trata del siguiente modo:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/modernizr/2.8.3/modernizr.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Ya lo he probado y desde la consola ya puedo acceder al objeto de `Modernizr`

Comment: :) Muchas gracias, ello ha funcionado!

Comment: donde te doy like por tu ayuda? como funciona?

Comment: en la flecha que indica hacia arriba justo a lado de mi respuesta

Comment: también por fas si puedes marcarla como correcta pára que le aparezca una palomita verde y quede como referencia para otras personas

Comment: 1000 Gracias!! :)